# Can I use a total of three displays with non-Retina MacBook Pro via USB?

Tags: mac, display, macbook-pro

Can I add one display via DisplayPort and two more via USB using this?
http://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/VIDU2DVIA/

Or is the max two external displays? Or one DisplayPort and one USB?

I have a GeForce 650M GPU in my MBP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That USB adaptor contains a graphics chipset (GPU). It's like a (low bandwidth) graphics card in a dongle. I'm pretty sure it doesn't leverage your internal GPU in any way, so I'm pretty sure you could add a ton of these and have lots and lots of (low bandwidth) displays.

I don't think USB 2.0 provides enough bandwidth for high framerate operations like watching HD videos and gaming, but it might be fine for windows with more mundane content.

By the way, did you notice this disclaimer from the page you linked to?...

```
Note: This release does not support OpenGL acceleration 
(3D hardware acceleration) so therefore applications and 
features that require OpenGL, Quartz Extreme, Quartz Composer
and other framework based on OpenGL will not be fully supported.  
Examples of such features are Keynote Presentations, iPhoto Slideshows 
and iMovie.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use more than two displays.

- Display port allows the daisy chaining multiple display monitors. Sometimes this works as intended, sometimes it does not. [This link to macrumours](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/09/16/apple-thunderbolt-display-with-multiple-monitors/) has some more information. I am not going to cut and paste it all.
- You can use a http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/press/releases/2011/dualhead2go_dp/triplehead2go_dp/macbook_pro_thunderbolt/">TripleHead2Go DP multi-monitor adaptor. The first sentence of that link says it all: `Add up to 3 displays to your new Apple notebook`.
- You can use USB based GPU's. These are easy, relative cheap and very slow compared to all other solutions.  If you just want to display a static spreadsheet then they are fine. Displaying animated, 3D or just rapidly changing images on them might work less than optimal.
- Finally, if you do not just have a plain display port but one of the Macs with thunderbolt you can even add an external GPU via that high bandwidth port. Ee.g. an external case with PCIe and PSU, and a AMD 5770. That specific card would allow up to three extra displays. There are other cards which allow more displays, but I know that one is tested and worked. In theory you could even add multiple external graphical cards for a dozen extra monitors.